# Visual Studio Mac error MT1006 with valid/correct provisioning file

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios

Trying to deploy a binary from Visual Studio Mac to a brand new iPad. I am using *exactly* the same *Signing Authority* and *Provisioning Profile* and entitlements file I have been using to push the app to the App Store since August.

Even with the correct provisioning data (I push to the App Store from this same Mac Mini) I get the dreaded MT1006 error:

```
ApplicationVerificationFailed: Failed to verify code signature of /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.3Eku4r/extracted/my.iOS.app : 0xe8008015 (A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.)
error MT1006: Could not install the application '/Users/john/Projects/[...]/bin/iPhone/Release/my.iOS.app' on the device 'John???s iPad': AMDeviceSecureInstallApplicationBundle returned: 0xe8008015.
```

Is there some extra step I am missing? What do I need to do to run the debug and release versions of my app on this iPad from Visual Studio?

Comment: Try to clean the project and rebuild again. You can see more detail from the [device log](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/enhanced-device-logging-in-visual-studio/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provisioning profiles for deployment to the App Store and debug deployment to a device are entirely distinct entities. Who knew? Went with *Automatic Provisioning* in Visual Studio, works fine. FYI.

Comment: deployment to the App Store use a production provisioning profile and deployment to a device use a development provisioning profile. You can mark this answer so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Comment: Automatic looked like it should have worked.  Sure reported provisioning etc.  But, failed.  A reboot of VS 2019 on windows 10, solution CLEAN, deleted bin and obj's then selected MANUAL PROVISIONING and "Unknown (VS: com.****.**** Development) " shows in the provisioning profile. 1st time I've seen anything here using Manual.  So, selected the iPad and it deployed and debug is working.   Note: iPad USB'd to mac mini.... amazing.